# @Name([CN];@UserName) is not working as expected in NotesView column

Tags: lotus-notes, notesview

I've created a Notes View and I wanna show (for some reason) the current user's name in all rows using this formula:

@Name([CN];@UserName)

This was supposed to show the current user name regardless of the document of the current row, but it shows different user names in different row instead, which is quite astonishing for me.

Note that I just wanna see the current user name in this columns on many users' desktop and later on I'll remove this column and will use this formula in some other column for a comparison purpose, which I know how to do.

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

The documentation explains that you can not do this:

> *When a formula runs on a server, the agent signer is considered the
> current user. Therefore, @UserName should only be used on local
> databases, where it will return the user's name. Using @UserName in
> server-based private views also returns the user's name, but produces
> unpredictable results if the views on the server are rebuilt using
> Updall. You should not use @UserName in a public view, doing so
> produces unpredictable results.*

Source: https://help.hcltechsw.com/dom_designer/12.0.2/basic/H_USERNAME.html

Comment: So what do i do to get current user name? In fact i want this in the View Selection Formula  to match user name from certain fields with this name to filter documents for the current user only.

Comment: From the same documentation: you need to use a private view